# How to get youtube video title from video url

Tags: android, android-studio

**Suppose i have this link " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU ". Now i want to get the title of this video and want to show it in my WebView()...
How to do this ??**

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
WebView browser;
EditText url_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    openURL();
}

public void openURL(){
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    url_text =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU";

            browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            browser.loadUrl(url);
            browser.getSettings().getDisplayZoomControls();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**I just want to get and print the title of the video that the url contains**

Answer (score 1):

Can use [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#youtube_data_api_tag_title)

```
URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
     &fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics

Description: This example modifies the fields parameter from example 3 so that in the API response, each video resource's snippet object only includes the channelId, title, and categoryId properties.

API response:

{
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy just by using a URL. You are going to need to use YouTube's API to get the title. This information comes from a JSON response.

Specific videos
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos?csw=1

API for Java
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java

Good luck